# Executing tasks with exception handling while updating GUI during tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0

Morning.

(Attempting to do): Im tryin to execute several tasks in parallel. Each task runs through a certain section of a text file using a for loop (1st task = rows 1-10. 2nd task = rows 11-20 etc). At the end of each row check, an event is raised and the GUI thread updates the UI ie "X rows have been checked."

(Stuck on):I dont understand how to do this and yet still be able to handle exceptions correctly. As far as im aware, i need to call

```
task.Wait();
```

or

```
task.WaitAll();
```

but by calling it, the UI thread just waits there and any events i fire inside the tasks to update the UI just get added the the UI's queue.

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Note: I apologise in advance if this is stupid but im having some issues with threading.

as the tasks bundle all exceptions into AggregateException and if i call task.Waitall(); the UI thread just seems to wait until the tasks are completed or an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to attach another task to your task, as a 'handler' to deal with any exceptions.

Here's an example:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    throw new Exception("oops!");
});

// attach an exception-handling task
task.ContinueWith(previousTask =>
{
    // do something with the exception
    Console.WriteLine(previousTask.Exception);      

}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```

Note that the task attached with `ContinueWith` has `TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted`, which means it will only run if the task it is attached to throws an exception.

This way, your exceptions can be handled asynchronously, and you don't need to wait on anything.

However, since you want to do a parallel for loop, I'd probably do something like:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    try 
    {
        Parallel.For(..., i => 
        {
            ... 
        });
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        // handle it somehow
    }
});
```

This way, your main task waits on all the child tasks, but the UI thread which spawned it doesn't have to wait.

The main thing you have to be sure of is that your `catch` clause (or the handling task in previous example) *never* throws an exception.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Thats pretty neat, one aspect im unsure of is if i have your first block of code (var task = Task...) enclosed in a for loop, is it possible to change the name of the task variable on each loop through the for loop?

Comment: @HansRudel: Actually, upon more thought, I think a different way would be better for your situation. I have updated with that example. It's pretty much the same as Henk's answer, though.

Comment: One last question. In the parallel.For, is it possible to assign different parameters to the method called with it? ie first task = a specific file path/row numbers, 2nd task = a different file path/row numbers etc. Im assuming a switch statement would be ok?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative (the simplest) is to handle the exception in the thread that threw it.

So you would need a try catch in the executing method - then what you do is up to your design, you could for example raise an error event that the UI could handle (still in the context of the exception thread).

Another alternative is that you could kick off your task scheduling code (ie the code that calls WaitAll()) as a BackgroundWorker - this will then leave the UI free to do its stuff (handle other input) - this is probably the better way to do it but may require a little re-factoring.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Regarding your second suggestion, off the top of ur head, do you know of a link which already has a similar example. If not, no worries ill have a dig around.